# filling rows of a df under conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a resampled df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nat = np.datetime64('NaT')


df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": [nat, nat, nat, '2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871', '2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871', nat, nat, nat, '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515'],
              "Power": [0, 0, 0, 4200, 4200, 0, 0, 0, 4200, 4200],
              "Total Energy": [5300, 5300, 5300, 5500, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5900, 6100],
              "ID": ['-', '-', '-', 1, 1, '-', '-', '-', 2, 2],
              "Energy": [0, 0, 0, 200, 300, 0, 0, 0, 300, 500]},
              index=pd.date_range(start = "2020-04-09 6:45", periods = 10, freq = 'T'))

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Power'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Power'], errors = 'ignore')
df['Total Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Energy'], errors = 'coerce')
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors = 'coerce')
df['Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Energy'], errors = 'coerce')

df
```

Output:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy      ID    Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:46:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:47:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871   4200           5500     1.0       200
2020-04-09 06:49:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871   4200           5600     1.0       300
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:51:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:52:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200           5900     2.0       300
2020-04-09 06:54:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200           6100     2.0       500
```

I have to fill the rows where `df.index < df['Time']` (rounded) and `df['Time'] == NaT` as followed:

- `df.index == df['Time']: df['Power'] = 0, df['Total Energy']` remains the same, `df['ID'] = df['ID'] of the df['Time'], df['Energy'] = 0`
- between these two rows the entries should be filled as follows: `df['Power'] = df['Energy']` @ `df['Time'] / ((df['Time'] (rounded) - df.index)/60)`, `df['Energy'] = df['Power'] * 1/60, df['Total Energy'] = df['Total Energy'].shift(1) + df['Energy'], df['ID'] = df['ID']` of the `df['Time']`

here the desired result:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy      ID    Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871      0           5300     1.0         0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871   6000           5400     1.0       100
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871   4200           5500     1.0       200
2020-04-09 06:49:00 2020-04-09 06:45:38.559871   4200           5600     1.0       300
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515      0           5600     2.0         0
2020-04-09 06:52:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   9000           5750     2.0       150
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200           5900     2.0       300
2020-04-09 06:54:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200           6100     2.0       500
```

the column `df['Time']` may also be changed to the rounded value:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy      ID    Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:46:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00      0           5300     1.0         0
2020-04-09 06:47:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00   6000           5400     1.0       100
2020-04-09 06:48:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00   4200           5500     1.0       200
2020-04-09 06:49:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00   4200           5600     1.0       300
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:51:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00      0           5600     2.0         0
2020-04-09 06:52:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00   9000           5750     2.0       150
2020-04-09 06:53:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00   4200           5900     2.0       300
2020-04-09 06:54:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00   4200           6100     2.0       500
```

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT**

to round `df['Time']` i found this:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.ceil('1min')
```

**Edit 2**

to adjust the column `df['Time']` I proceeded as follows:

```
dates = df['Time'].unique()    
for date in dates:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if index == date:
                df.loc[index, 'Time'] = date
```

how I get the `df[ID]` of the corresponding column (`df['Time']`) I don't know yet.
I also filled the rows as follows:

```
#scheme for filling the nan-values
s = df['Time'].ffill()
x = df['Time'].bfill()
g = df['Time'].mask(s.eq(x), s)

#Filling time
df['Time'] = df['Time'].groupby(g).ffill()

#Filling ID
df3['ID'] = df2['ID'].groupby(df2['Time']).bfill()
```

Output:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy      ID    Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT      0           5300     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:46:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00      0           5300     1.0         0
2020-04-09 06:47:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00      0           5300     1.0         0
2020-04-09 06:48:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00   4200           5500     1.0       200
2020-04-09 06:49:00        2020-04-09 06:46:00   4200           5600     1.0       300
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT      0           5600     NaN         0
2020-04-09 06:51:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00      0           5600     2.0         0
2020-04-09 06:52:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00      0           5600     2.0         0
2020-04-09 06:53:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00   4200           5900     2.0       300
2020-04-09 06:54:00        2020-04-09 06:51:00   4200           6100     2.0       500
```

that is still missing: the values for `df['Power']/ df['Energy']` and `df['Total Energy']` must be calculated and changed as described above.

Comment: Interesting, but too specific question. In cases like this, you should explain better the way you need to implement the data transformations. Please improve the way you explain the formulas for updating `power` column.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! Most of the points I ansered and added by myself, for people, who have similar problems. For the column `power` the column `energy` is neccessary. `power = energy*60`. For the column `energy` it is enough, if it is filled linear, if there is a `time` entry. `Total Energy` can be calculated by adding or subtracting the last value of `energy`.
I hope this makes my problem clearer and you can help dealing with it :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given your desired output and what you told me in your comment, I did this:

```
time_bfill = df['Time'].bfill()
df['Time2'] = df['Time'].mask(df.index.to_series().ge(time_bfill), time_bfill)

id_bfill = df['ID'].bfill()
df['ID2'] = df['ID'].mask(df.index.to_series().ge(time_bfill), id_bfill)

df['Energy2'] = df['Energy'].mask((df['Time'].isnull()) & (df['Time2'].notna()) & (df.index.to_series().ne(df['Time2'])), np.NaN)
df['Energy3'] = df['Energy2'].interpolate(limit_direction='both', limit_area='inside')

df['Power2'] = df['Power'].mask(df['Power'] == 0, 60 * df['Energy3'])
df['Total Energy2'] = df['Total Energy'].mask(df['Power'] == 0, df['Total Energy'] + df['Energy3'])

df
```

and got this dataframe:

[image: DF after calculations]

Consider the columns with greatest suffixes. I left them here for you to see the intermediate steps.

You can adjust that code so as to avoid some of the intermediate columns, but be careful, since in some cases the original values are needed by other columns, generated after them.

A quick way to get rid of those intermediate columns, is running this at the end:

```
df[['Time', 'Power', 'Total Energy', 'ID', 'Energy']] = df[['Time2', 'Power2', 'Total Energy2', 'ID2', 'Energy3']]
df.drop(['Time2', 'Power2', 'Total Energy2', 'ID2', 'Energy3', 'Energy2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df
```

and you get:

[image: DF after replacements]